# error in fourth deletion case linked list program

Tags: c

when there are more than one strings are presents in linked list at deletion it gives runtime error see case 4, when there is only one node in linked list it deletes properly when there are multiple then it gives run time error

```
            #include<stdio.h>
            #include<stdlib.h>
            #include<string.h>
            typedef struct dll
            {
                char data[87];
            struct dll *next , *back;

            }node;
            node *first=NULL, *last=NULL, *temp=NULL, *prev=NULL;
            void main()
            {
                char ndel[50];
                char sentence[80];
                int  len;
                int freq[26];
                int  vowels = 0, consonants = 0, special = 0;

                int ky,sch,ch,i,j,flag=0,count=0,pos;

            while(1)
            {
        printf("\n =======================String Operations Using Doubliy             linklist===============\n");
        printf("\n1: Create 2: display \n 3:insert 4:delete \n 5:find Vovels & Consonants 6:count \n7:Reverse Linked list  8:occurence \n9:Exit\n");
            printf("\n enter ur choice \n");
            scanf("%d",&ch);
            switch(ch)
            {
                case 1:
                    temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
                    printf("                   ==>Enter String in linked list\n\n");
                    scanf("%s",&temp->data);
                    temp->back=NULL;
                    temp->next=NULL;
                    if(count==0)
                    {
                        first=temp;
                        last=temp;
                        count++;
                        printf("\n                   ==>First String is added\n\n");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        temp->back=last;
                        last->next=temp;
                        last=temp;
                        count++;
                        printf("\n                   ==>String added in linked list \n\n");

                    }
                    break;
                    case 2:
                        if(count==0)
                        {
                            printf("\n                   ==>linked list is empty\n\n");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            temp=first;
                            printf("                   ==>Strings of linked-List\n\n");
                            for(i=1;i<=count;i++)
                            {
                                printf("\n == %s == \n",temp->data);
                                temp=temp->next;
                            }

                        }
                        break;


                 case 3:
                    temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
                    printf("\n                   ==>Enter String which wants to insert \n\n");
                    scanf("%s",&temp->data);
                    temp->next=NULL;
                    temp->back=NULL;
                    printf("\n\n         ==> Where u wants to enter \n          1: At Starting\n          2: At End\n ");
                    scanf("%d",&sch);
                    switch(sch)
                    {
                        case 1:
                        if(count==0)
                        {
                        first=temp;
                        last=temp;
                        count++;
                        printf("\n\n          ==>String is inserted at First position only one present \n\n");
                        }
                else
                        {   
                        temp->next=first;
                        first->back=temp;
                        first=temp;
                        count++;
                        printf("\n\n                         =>String inserted at begining \n\n");
                        }
                        break;  
                        case 2:
                        if(count==0)
                        {
                        first=temp;
                        last=temp;
                        count++;
                        printf("\n\n                         =>String is inserted at 1 position only one present \n\n");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            last->next=temp;
                            temp->back=last;
                            last=temp;
                            count++;
                            printf("\n \n                         =>String is inserted at last \n\n");
                        }   

                        }
                    break;

            case 4:
                    printf("\nenter element which wants to be deleted\n");      
                    scanf("%s",ndel);
                    temp=first;
                    prev=first;
                    for(i=1;i<=count;i++)
                    {
                        if(strcmp(ndel, temp->data)==0)
                        {
                            if(prev==temp)
                            {
                                if(temp->next==NULL)
                                {
                                    first=temp;
                                    last=temp;
                                    free(temp);
                                    count--;
                                    flag=1;
                                    printf("\n data is deleted \n");
                            }
                                 else                   
                                 {
                                    temp->next=first;
                                    temp->back=NULL;
                                    first->back=NULL;
                                    free(temp);
                                    count--;
                                    flag=1;
                                    printf("\n data is deleted \n");

                                 }
                            }
                                    else
                                    {
                                    prev->next=temp->next;
                                    (temp->next)->back=prev;
                                    free(temp);
                                    count--;
                                    flag=1;
                                    printf("\n data is deleted \n");                                                
                                    }
                                }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        prev=temp;
                                        temp=temp->next;
                                    }
                                         }  
                                         if(flag==0)
                                         {
                                            printf("\n sorry  data is not found\n");
                                                      } 
                                                            break;          


                    case 5:
                        if(count==0)
                        {
                            printf("***********************linked list is empty***********************\n\n");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            temp=first;
                            printf("                   ==>Strings of linked-List\n\n");
                            for(j=1;j<=count;j++)

                            {   

                                printf("%s ",temp->data);

                       for (i = 0; temp->data[i] != '\0'; i++)
                        {
                            if ((temp->data[i] == 'a' || temp->data[i] == 'e' || temp->data[i] ==
                            'i' || temp->data[i] == 'o' || temp->data[i] == 'u') ||
                            (temp->data[i] == 'A' || temp->data[i] == 'E' || temp->data[i] ==
                            'I' || temp->data[i] == 'O' || temp->data[i] == 'U'))
                            {
                                vowels = vowels + 1;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                consonants = consonants + 1;
                            }

                        }   
                            temp=temp->next;        
                }
                            temp=first;
                            for(i=1;i<=count;i++)
                            {
                            //  printf(" %s ",temp->data);
                                temp=temp->next;
                            }



                           printf("\n\n           No. of vowels in given String Linkedlist  = %d\n",  vowels);
                            printf("\n          No. of consonants in given String Linkedlist  = %d\n", consonants);
                            consonants=0;
                            vowels=0;
                            special=0;

                        }
                        break;

            case 6:
                           if(count==0)
                           {
                            printf("\n                         =>no Strings\n");

                              }
                              else
                              {
                                printf("\n                         =>count == %d\n",count);
                                 }   
                                 break;
                        case 7:
                           temp=last;
                           for(i=1;i<=count;i++)
                           {
                            printf("\n                         => %s \n",temp->data);

                           temp=temp->back;
                                    }
                                    break;

                        case 8:
                        if(count==0)
                        {
                            printf("****************linked list is empty****************\n\n");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            temp=first;
                            //printf("Strings of linked-List\n\n");
                            for(j=1;j<=count;j++)
                            {

                                //printf("\n == %s == \n",temp->data);
                           len = strlen(temp->data);


                        for(i=0; i<26; i++)
                        {
                            freq[i] = 0;
                        }



                        for(i=0; i<len; i++)
                        {

                            if(temp->data[i]>='a' && temp->data[i]<='z')
                            {
                                freq[temp->data[i] - 97]++;
                            }
                            else if(temp->data[i]>='A' && temp->data[i]<='Z')
                            {
                                freq[temp->data[i] - 65]++;
                            }
                        }



                    printf("\n         Frequency of all characters in string:  %s \n",temp->data);
                        for(i=0; i<26; i++)
                        {

                            if(freq[i] != 0)
                            {

                               printf("                    '%c' = %d\n",(i + 97), freq[i]);
                            }
                        }

                                temp=temp->next;
                            }





                break;

                        case 9:
                            exit(1);


            }

                }}}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This obviously contains way more than necessary.

Comment: Wow, that's some creative formatting. Please use a standard indentation convention for easier reading.

Comment: What is the input that leads to an error?

Comment: when i enter string to delete and if there are more than one nodes are present in linked list then there is error occur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following is your issue here.
In case the list is as such where you wish to delete the element 3:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 ->NULL
```

Then in second iteration `prev` points to `2` and `temp` points to `3`.

In your code i.e.

```
else
{
   prev->next=temp->next;
   (temp->next)->back=prev;
   free(temp);
   count--;
   flag=1;
   printf("\n data is deleted \n");                                                
}
```

More precisely in the statement `(temp->next)->back=prev;`, you are accessing `back` of `temp->next`, where `temp->next` happens to be NULL. I think this is the source of your error!